# Natbib - how do I sort citations chronologically (i.e. by year) while references are sorted alphabetically in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm trying to have citations in chronological order (by year), through natbib.sty

I'm getting the Output

```
Maulik et al (2020a); Albert et al (2020a); Maulik et al (2020b); McKeon &
Sharma (2010)
```

I need the output like below

```
McKeon & Sharma (2010); Albert et al (2020a); Maulik et al (2020a,2020b)
```

how to get the citation order by year through natbib?

here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}%%INTcrop, INTpagegrid
\usepackage[authoryear,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{isect1}

\noindent \citet{Maulik2020a,Maulik2020b,McKeon and Sharma2010,Albert2020a}

\medskip

\noindent \citet{Maulik2020a,Maulik2020b,McKeon and Sharma2010,Albert2020a}


\medskip

\noindent \textit{Fluid big data}, i.e. high resolution data in both space and time, have been accumulated in the fluid dynamics community thanks to the recent progress in numerical simulations, e.g. direct numerical simulation (DNS) and large eddy simulation (LES), and experimental techniques, e.g. particle




\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Maulik \textit{et al} (2020a)]{Maulik2020a}
Maulik R, Fukami K, Ramachandra N, Fukagata K and Taira K 2020a Probabilistic neural networks for fluid flow surrogate modeling and data recovery arXiv:2005.04271 [physics.flu-dyn]


\bibitem[Albert \textit{et al} (2020a)]{Albert2020}
Albert 2020a Probabilistic neural networks for fluid flow surrogate modeling and data recovery arXiv:2005.04271 [physics.flu-dyn]


\bibitem[Maulik \textit{et al} (2020b)]{Maulik2020b}
Maulik R, Egele R, Lusch B and Balaprakash P 2020b Recurrent neural network architecture search for geophysical emulation \textit{arXiv:2004.10928} [physics.comp-ph]

\bibitem[McKeon \& Sharma (2010)]{McKeon and Sharma2010}
McKeon B J and Sharma A S 2010 A critical-layer framework for turbulent pipe flow \textit{J. Fluid Mech.} \textbf{658} 336---382

\bibitem[Morimoto \textit{et al} (1997)]{Morimoto2020}
Morimoto M, Fukami K and Fukagata K 2020 Experimental velocity data estimation for imperfect particle images using machine learning \textit{arXiv:2005.00756} [physics.flu-dyn]

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you use BibTeX to generate the bibliography for you or do you directly write it into `thebibliohgraphy` by hand?

Comment: `natbib` has no official interface to sort in-text citations differently from the sort order in the bibliography, but it is possible to hack something together: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/549708/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484172/35864. In principle this idea can also be used if you generate your bibliography manually, but you would have to manually give the desired sort order.

Comment: @moewe, directly write it into thebibliohgraphy by hand