# How to sort citations by year with \citep

Tags: citing, natbib, sorting, bibliographystyle

How can I automatically sort the in-text citations by year? For example, I want that

```
\citep{a2013,b1993,c2010,d2021}
```

automatically yields

(Author B (1993), Author C (2010), Author A (2013), Author D (2021))

I have tried something like `\usepackage[sort]{natbib}`, but it does not seem to work. I am using the abbrvnat.bst from [this bioRxiv preprint template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws). Here is [my file](https://justpaste.it/dqblj). Any ideas?

Comment: The sorting in citations, if enabled, will usually be the same that you have in the bibliography. So this will generally not give you citations sorted by year. In theory something else could be done, but requires some work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/549708/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484172/35864

Comment: @moewe - The `abbrvnat` bibliography style (which the OP appears to claim to be using) does sort the entries by authors' surnames. As I report in the answer I just posted, I am unable to reproduce the OP's output. Instead, I get a citation call-out with all entries sorted chronologically.

Comment: The file `abbrvnat.bst` is a standard part of all TeX distributions. There's no need to provide a hyperlink to a copy of this file.

Comment: @Mico You get chronological sorting if all entries are by the same authors, but if you have different authors the names, the names are more relevant, so the citations are not generally sorted chronologically.

Comment: @moewe - It looks like I got fooled by the OP's write-up, then. I had assumed that the four "Citation" entries were all authored by the same person(s). That wasn't smart of me... I've gone ahead and deleted my answer as it's not likely to be irrelevant.

Comment: @Mico No problem! I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @samwolfe - Thanks. Do give `\citet{b1993}, \citet{c2010}, \citet{a2013}, and \citet{d2021}` a try. Makin this adjustment is, thankfully, a one-time chore.